# Using Kubectl to remove a service without using an online resource

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I have followed the getting started instructions here: https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/

Please see the command below:

```
kubectl kustomize kustomize/deployment | \
linkerd inject - | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

emojivoto is now installed an accessible as I expected.

How can I remove emojivoto? This appears to work:

```
kubectl delete -f https://run.linkerd.io/emojivoto.yml
```

However, is it possible to do this without using an online resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course possible: The mentioned yaml consists of multiple object definitions. 
For example namespaces and service accounts.

Each of them can be deleted using `kubectl delete <type> <name>`.

Since all objects are created in the namespace `emojivoto` it is possible to remove everything by just removing the namespace: `kubectl delete namespace emojivoto`.

The other option is to save the yaml file locally and use `kubectl delete -f <file>` instead.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  Realised both your options just after I posted the question